# Cannot visualize a WMS in Geoserver from a JPG file

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms

I'm using a JPG file (8bit unsigned), together with a .jgw and the .jpg.aux.xml having the projection. The image displays well in ArcGIS and QGIS.

Now I want to create the image in Geoserver 2.11.0 as a 'WorldImage' store, and then create a Web Map Service around it. But the image doesn't work in 'Layer preview'. You see nothing.

When I try to consume the WMS in ArcGIS, this is the error I get.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try increasing the amount of heap space?

Comment: But increasing the heap size is not really the right thing to do. You have obviously quite a large jpeg file and for reading any data from a jpeg image you must uncompress the whole file. Convert you image into a tiled, internally jpeg-compressed GeoTIFF, add overviews into the image, and you can use it much faster on GeoServer, QGIS, and ArcGIS.

Comment: will `gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co TILED=YES input.jpg output.tif` do the job?

Comment: Yes. Photointerpretation YCBCR may yield smaller images but it depends on what sort of image you have. Assigning projection with -a_srs is probably a good idea too.